# xpages dojo calendar script SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: dojo, xpages

Hello I'm receiving the following js error within my xpages app. It is in relation to the calendar widget. Oddly enough this code runs on a server perfectly fine, however when I try accessing the same server, same app through a firewall, that's when I receive the following js error. Unfortunately this is compressed js and I don't know what anything is doing to be able to resolve the issue on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
failed loading /xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/../dijit/Calendar.js with error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
https://newwads.health.state.ny.us/+CSCO+d6756767633A2F2F7565766665696534++/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js
Line 14

failed loading /xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/../dijit/Calendar.js with error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
toString(uri=

undefined

, _25=

undefined

, cb=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
toString(_21=

"../dijit/Calendar.js"

, _22=

"dijit.Calendar"

, cb=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
toString(_2d=

"dijit.Calendar"

, _2e=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
eval()56 (line 8)
toString(_1d=

"/*\r\n Copyright (c) 2004...jit/form/DateTextBox.js"

)dojo.js (line 14)
toString(uri=

"/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroo...jit/form/DateTextBox.js"

, cb=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
toString(uri=

"/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroo...jit/form/DateTextBox.js"

, _25=

"dijit.form.DateTextBox"

, cb=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
toString(_21=

"../dijit/form/DateTextBox.js"

, _22=

"dijit.form.DateTextBox"

, cb=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
toString(_2d=

"dijit.form.DateTextBox"

, _2e=

undefined

)dojo.js (line 14)
()testTime.xsp (line 21)


...dium"){return 4;}if(_171.slice&&_171.slice(-2)=="px"){return parseFloat(_171);}w...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your proxy messing with the data? Like single-signon or adding code? You could use Fiddler and see what is going on. Also AFAIK the FF WebDeveloper allows to see the loaded JS uncompressed

Comment: I'll check out fiddler to see how much further I can get. Wasn't able (or not sure ) how to set any in breakpoints in firebug with compressed js, made it difficult to track up to now.

Comment: Still not resolved, however after checking on Chrome browser (I didn't have much luck in deciphering how to use the fiddler tool yet) I started noticing that the proxy is adding a 'CSCO_GHOST' script after each of dojo calls. I'll have to investigate how or why this extra code is being added and if there is a way around it, or if I need assistance from firewall admins.

Comment: So it *is* the firewall messing up your data

Comment: It appears that the firewall is main culprit here. I'll need to contact the firewall admins for help here, as I am not sure where to proceed next. While the answer to what may be causing it is likely identified, how to fix is still open for me.  Will follow up after I contact the firewall people.

Comment: I ended up removing the calendar widget. I wasn't able to use calendar picker either through the portal.  Not sure if the following link is any clue, but might be related for anyone else checking this out: http://www.cisco.com/web/software/280775065/38969/ASA-832-Interim-Release-Notes.html

Is the following note, but no further details....


CSCti03135
Search using Dojo Toolkit fails across WebVPN with 404 Error